# How to get root folder of project, two level up

Tags: go, path

Im inside deep folder inside file and I want to get the dir which is 2 level up, I see the following api but not sure how to add something like 
"../../" , any idea?

```
  dir, err := os.Getwd()
```

for example I  get the following

```
/Users/i02222333/go/src/myapp/src/test
```

And I need

```
/Users/i02222333/go/src/myapp
```

I can cut the string with the path with some manipulation but my question is if there is better solution to do it with golang ?

Comment: run the executable from `/Users/i02222333/go/src/myapp` then. Where the source code/project is doesn't really matter, what matters is from which folder you start the executable.

Comment: @tkausl - I run the command inside the test file (the end of the first path) , there I should know that path in 2 level up `myapp`, how should I do it? can you provide example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the directory name of '../../' using the `path` package like this:

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path"
)

func main() {
    dirname, err := os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Current directory: %v\n", dirname)
    dir, err := os.Open(path.Join(dirname, "../../"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Name of ../../: %v\n", dir.Name())
}
```

Here is an example of my output:

```
$ go run main.go
Current directory: /Users/jack/go/src/stackoverflow/example/directory
Name of ../../: /Users/jack/go/src/stackoverflow
```

Comment: You should be using `filepath` rather than `path` for file paths, and if you're going through the motions of joining rather than simple string concatenation, don't hardcode the `/` separator in there.